# Mtp-Host Application

Tags: android, usb

Is there any application available in Android Market that used USB/MTP Api's?
        tell any information that will be useful for me in making android MTP Application?

Answer (score 2):

I think this might help:

[Honeycomb-MTP-sample](https://github.com/ynakanishi/Honeycomb-MTP-sample)

It's a sample application that uses MTP to read camera contents.

Answer (score 0):

I think camerabrower also gives you something about MTP/HOST.